# FxCop CA1047 - Abstract and accessibility level

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract, fxcop, fxcopcmd

I have this code (sample to reproduce):

```
public class ObjectBase<T>
{
}
public abstract class ExportBase
{
    public void ExportData<T>(string path, T data, string filename)
                where T : ObjectBase<T>
    {
        // Several verifications on data.
        // Example:
        if (data != null)
        {
            this.InnerExport(this.GetFileName<T>(path, filename), data);
        }
    }
    protected abstract void InnerExport<T>(string path, T data)
                where T : ObjectBase<T>;

    public string GetFileName<T>(string path, string filename)
    {
        // Code.
        return "TEST";
    }
}
internal sealed class XmlExport : ExportBase
{
    protected override void InnerExport<T>(string path, T data)
    {
        // Code.
    }
}
```

I don't want XmlExport visible (internal in my class library) nor inherits (sealed).

With FxCop 10.0, I've got an `CA1047:DoNotDeclareProtectedMembersInSealedTypes`:

> **Name:** (FxCopCmd)
>   Do not declare protected members in sealed types.
>
> **Description:** (FxCopCmd)
>   Sealed types cannot be extended, and protected members
>   are only useful if you can extend the declaring type. Sealed types
>   should not declare protected members.
>
> **How to fix:** (FxCopCmd)
>   Make member 'XmlExport.InnerExport(string, T)' private,
>   public, or internal (Friend in Visual Basic).
>
> **Info:** (FxCop)
>   Sealed types cannot be extended, and protected members 
>   are only useful if you can extend the declaring type.
>   Sealed types should not declare protected members.

But I can't change protected to private: virtual or abstract members can't be private.
Nor public (does not make sense, here).

I know I can use a `SuppressMessage`, but I'm wondering if there is a better way (including a modification of the classes).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be due to a bug in the rule, triggered by the generic constraint ("where T : ObjectBase") on the base InnerExport method declaration.  You should suppress the violation as a false positive.  If you're feeling particularly keen, you could also report the bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/.

Comment: Agreed.  If you report the bug on connect, post the link and I'll vote it up.

Comment: Well, didn't expected that ^^  I've post my first bug on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789199/fxcop-ca1047-abstract-and-accessibility-level) So, I'll suppress it as you suggest, Nicole Calinoiu. Thanks.

Comment: The bug is closed as external tools : "The product team itself no longer directly accepting feedback for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and earlier products"...

Comment: The problem is still present in VS 2012 Code Analysis.  Maybe the product team would feel more responsible for that one.  Then again, maybe not...

Answer (score 0):

You could change protected to `internal` if you only will use this in the library. But you would also have to change it to `internal` in `XmlExport` when you override.

Comment: If I change to internal in both, I can have access to InnerExport outside of the classes (inside my library). So, I would like to avoid this solution. I'm not the only one who could work on it, so, even if a write 'DO NOT USE' on the comments... But I keep it in mind.